# How to design different kinds of (nearly) the same (in Scala)

Tags: scala, generics, design-patterns, .obj, wavefront

I have the following problem (in Scala)...

I want to read [wavefront](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) files (.obj) and transform them to something I can work with later.
The wavefront files I want to support are files with the following definitions for:

- TypeA: vertices and faces
- TypeB: vertices, texture and faces
- TypeC: vertices, normals and faces
- TypeD: vertices, textures, normals and faces

I will read them and create a Mesh (a model class for later use) of it with the following fields:

- TypeA: `Array[Float]`, `Array[Int]`
- TypeB: `Array[Float]`, `Array[Float]`, `Array[Int]`
- TypeC: `Array[Float]`, `Array[Float]`, `Array[Int]`
- TypeD: `Array[Float]`, `Array[Float]`, `Array[Float]`, `Array[Int]`

I discovered two approaches:

**1. Approach:**

each type gets it's own model class

- TypeA: `case class TypeA(vertices: Array[Float], index: Array[Float])`
- TypeB: `case class TypeB(vertices: Array[Float], textures: Array[Float], index: Array[Float])`
- TypeC: `case class TypeC(vertices: Array[Float], normals: Array[Float], index: Array[Float])`
- TypeD: `case class TypeD(vertices: Array[Float], textures: Array[Float], normals: Array[Float], index: Array[Float])`

With this approach I don't have to check if all fields are present. I can use them out of the box. The disadvantage is: I need to create a "build"-method for each type (something like: `createTypeAFromFile(filename: String)`)

**2. Approach**
I create something like a uber-model:

```
case class Mesh(vertices: Array[Float], textures: Option[Array[Float]], normals: Option[Array[Float]], index: Array[Float])
```

With this approach I only need one "build"-method, but the problem here, later I have to check if the fields I want to use are really present (for normals and textures)

**Question:**

Does anyone knows a better approach/design, for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2):

It normally helps if you know the operations you will perform on the types, a good blog post is:  https://www.sandimetz.com/blog/2016/1/20/the-wrong-abstraction where the author argues that wrong abstraction is way worse than having some duplication.

Go with approach 1, maybe create a trait for all of them, and you will see if you can group them into types and if it is worth it.

Answer (score 2):

[Updates thanks to @simpadjo ]

Approach 3 is to create a trait hierarchy to represent the different options:

```
trait Faces {
  def vertices: Array[Float]
  def faces: Array[Float]
}
trait Textures extends Faces {
  def textures: Array[Float]
}
trait Normals extends Faces {
  def normals: Array[Float]
}
trait Obj3D extends Textures with Normals 

class A(
  val vertices: Array[Float],
  val faces: Array[Float]
) extends Faces

class B(
  val vertices: Array[Float],
  val textures: Array[Float],
  val faces: Array[Float]
) extends Textures

class C(
  val vertices: Array[Float],
  val normals: Array[Float],
  val faces: Array[Float]
) extends Normals

class D(
  val vertices: Array[Float],
  val textures: Array[Float],
  val normals: Array[Float],
  val faces: Array[Float]
) extends Obj3D
```

The parser can return `Faces` but it creates the appropriate subclass if the additional fields are available. You can then create a `Mesh` of `Faces` but use `match` to detect the case where additional information is available.

Comment: Like it. One comment: since there is no implementation inheritance (which is good) `trait Textures extends Faces` looks less arcane for me than `trait Textures { Faces =>` . Also declarations of concrete classes become shorter: `class D extends Normals`

Comment: I don't get it completely... why do I need a `Obj3D` trait? Would it be sufficient to have `classD(val vertices ...) extends Faces with Texture with Normals`? (and why needs `Textures` and `Normals` extends `Faces` --> example `class B(val vertices) extends Faces with with Textures`)

Comment: The reason for the different traits is so that you can use them later to say type which type you need. e.g `def reverseNormals(norms: Normals)` would only work on `C` or `D`. Likewise you can `match` on the specific type you need.